# Unable to create an anonymous object

Tags: java

I tried doing this:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener( {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        

    }
});
```

And it gives me a compilation error called syntax error on token "(" and ")".

Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong. I want to create an anonymous object of the class implementing interface ActionListener.

Comment: You misplaced the paranthesis

Answer (score 2):

You're using the content of the anonymous class as parameter to the constructor of `ActionListener`. Close the parenthesis first, then add the body of the anonymous class:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your parenthesis

```
                                             ↓<<<<<<<+
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener( {      |
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     |  
                                                     |  
    }                                                |
});                                                  |
 ^>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+
```

In other words you need first to invoke constructor `new ActionListener()` and then add body of anonymous class `{...}`

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        

    }
};
```

You can't pass code block as argument `new ActionListener( {...} )`